# Quater Toss Guessing Game Python

Tags: python, random

I wanted to make this work but for some reason i cant get the tails side to work it keeps on showing 1. Also take note am still new at python.

I also want to make loop. Lets say they don't get the number they guessed on. So if they say no (it starts the game again) or yes (it gives them a thanks for playing)

This is what i have so far.

```
import random

print 'Welcome to Heads or Tails Guessing Game'
print ''
print 'Lets say I toss a Quater up in the air. What are the chances it will come up heads or even tails every time split even? 5 times or even 5000 times. Choose an ejucated guess.'
raw_input ('What would your number be? ')
tossQuater, itsHeads, itsTails = 1,1,1
while tossQuater < 5000:
    if random.randint(1,500) == 1:
        itsHeads = itsHeads + 1
        itstails = itsTails + 1
    tossQuater = tossQuater + 1

    if tossQuater == 1300:
        print 'First 1,500 tosses. Heads will come up ' + str(itsHeads) + ' times.' ' But for Tails it came up ' + str(itsTails)+ ' times.'
    if tossQuater == 1900:
        print 'Second 2,000 tosses. Heads will come up ' + str(itsHeads) + ' times damm!.' ' But for Tails it came up ' + str(itsTails)+ ' times.'
    if tossQuater == 3050:
        print 'Third and final 1,500 tosses. Heads will come up ' + str(itsHeads) + ' times...' ' But for Tails it came up ' + str(itsTails)+ ' times...'

print ''
print 'Out of 5 times or even 5000 times. Well the number of heads showed out to be.' + str(itsHeads) + ' times! ' ' But from Tails it showed ' + str(itsTails) + ' times..'
raw_input ('\n\nDid the number you choose was the right one?')
```

Comment: `itstails = itsTails + 1` creates a new variable with different capitalization. (Your logic is also horribly broken since you attempt to increment both the Heads and Tails counters when the same event happens, which makes no sense at all...)

Comment: ^this ..... try this change     
`if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
    itsHeads = itsHeads + 1
else:
    itsTails = itsTails + 1
tossQuater = tossQuater + 1` 
 Sorry about the messed up indent

Comment: Opps that was bad on my part. Thanks for the correction @Wooble

Comment: Thanks @omu_negru ill give it a shot. any other feed back is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You're incrementing the itstails variable and printing out the itsTails variable. So, when you print out the itsTails variable, it shows 1 (because it hasn't been incremented). Your code should be like

```
itsTails = itsTails+1
```

Apart from that, your logic also seems to be flawed. I would have preferred the following code:

```
import random

while tossQuater < 5000:
    if random.randint(1,2) == 1:
        itsHeads = itsHeads + 1
    else:
        itsTails = itsTails + 1
    tossQuater = tossQuater + 1
```

I am setting a condition that if I get 1, it would be heads and if I get 2, it would be tails. This is a fair assumption, however not a perfectly realistic one, because even the randint method would generate a number based on some inbuilt function.

Answer (score 1):

To your general question, you need to work on your logic. Why would you add 1 to both "itsHeads" and "itsTails" at the same time?

Also, you need to look at how "randint" works. As it is now, you are tossing a 500 sided coin and only checking to see if it lands on one of those sides.

There are more logic errors. You seem to be using a lot of specific numbers here. Is there a reason for this? Please edit some of these to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I have re-written a bit of your code as I was not sure what you were trying to do in the middle section. The below will continually loop until the users declares that they don't want to continue playing.

I have made a function to play the game and toss the coin, feel free to ask if you have any quesiotns about functions or anything else

```
 import random


def toss(flips):
    heads=0;tails=0
    for i in range(0,flips):
        if random.random()>0.5:
            heads+=1
    return heads

def guessing_game():
    print 'Welcome to Heads or Tails Guessing Game'
    print ''
    print '''Lets say I toss a Quater up in the air 5000 imes.
            How many times will it come up heads?
            5 times or even 5000 times. Choose an educated guess.'''
    guess = raw_input ('What would your number be? ')

    ## compare the guess and the answer
    heads=toss(5000)
    print 'You guessed '+str(guess)+' heads and the actual answer was '+str(heads)
    if heads==guess:
        print 'Well Done'
    else:
        print 'Better luck next time'

    return  raw_input ('\n\n Do you want to play again (y/n)?')


play='y'
while play<>'n':
    play= guessing_game()
```